# java.lang.VerifyError after bytecode injection

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is really so easy to inject bytecode into android apps, so I decided to try it. I quickly coded 2 apps with eclipse (wich are both working), used apktool to get the bytecode and injected code from the one to the other. After fixing the AndroidMainfest.xml I builded the new app, signated it and installd it. I got a crash message, so I decided to take a closer look using LogCat. For result I got a java.lang.VerifyError. I tried injecting my code in an other, older (3rd party) app and that worked.

So can you say, that "new" released apps "safe" but older apps "unsafe"?

Comment: I used apktool go get smail of both apps. Than i pasted the packages from the one to the other app and invoked one kf the classes. This is what I mean with injection.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I can't comment, so I write my experiences in an answer. I've encountered the following situations for VerifyError:

- Wrong number of local registers. If you use more registers than the original code, change the number after `.locals`
- Wrong function signatures.